# Delete multiple lines from text file

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method to delete some of the text from my txt file. I started by checking if a string that I have exist in the file:

```
public boolean ifConfigurationExists(String pathofFile, String configurationString)
    {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(pathofFile);
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            list.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        if(list.contains(configurationString))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Since the string I want to delete contains multiple lines (String configurationString = "This\nis a\n multiple lines\n string";) I started by creating a new array of strings and splitting the string into array members.

```
public boolean deleteCurrentConfiguration(String pathofFile, String configurationString)
{
    String textStr[] = configurationString.split("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r");

    File inputFile = new File(pathofFile);
    File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(trimmedLine.equals(textStr[0])) continue;
        writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    writer.close(); 
    reader.close(); 
    boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);

    return true;
}
```

Can someone please help on how to delete the string from the txt file and also the line before and after the string?

Comment: One does not "delete lines from a file".  The only possibility is to make a copy of the file and not write out the unwanted lines as it is being copied.

Comment: You can of course remove part of a string but like Jim I would advise against working directly with the file. Anyway the Scanner can't write directly to the file you are in a read-only mode. You can use replace or substring methode from java.lang.String to get the content from your original file and write it in a new File

Comment: Yes I am doing something like this:

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this, though one way I do it is to firstly read the files content into an array of Strings by line (looks like you already did this), then to remove the data you don't want, and write to the file line-by-line the new information you do want.

To remove lines before the line you don't want, the line you don't want, and the line after you don't want, you could something like this:

```
List<String> newLines=new ArrayList<>();
boolean lineRemoved = false;
for (int i=0, i < lines.length; i++) {
  if (i < lines.length-1 && lines.get(i+1).equals(lineToRemove)) {
    // this is the line before it
  } else if (lines.get(i).equals(lineToRemove)) {
    // this is the line itself
    lineRemoved = true;
  } else if (lineRemoved == true) {
    // this is the line after the line you want to remove
    lineRemoved = false; // set back to false so you don't remove every line after the one you want
  } else
    newLines.add(lines.get(i));
}
// now write newLines to file
```

Note that this code is rough and untested, but should get you where you need to be.

Comment: The problem is that I have a String that contains four lines in it and I have to delete the line before these lines and the line after these lines

Comment: So you want only the remaining 4 lines, which you have in memory?

Comment: That say this is file.txt:
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h

myString = "c\nd\ne\nf"
I want after running the method, file.txt to be:
a
h